# TCP Transport to send message to Java TCP Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is there any documentation about how to use TCP transport to send message to other Java TCP server? 
I tried to google it but I only found some examples about how to use TCP Transport as listener (server). 
Is it possible to use this TCP transport in WSO2 to send message to other Java TCP Server?

Answer (score 0):

Since WSO2 ESB uses Axis2 Transport you can use, http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/transports/tcp-transport.html

and from configuration perspective use, http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/TCP+Transport